# How can I find local permaculturalists in my area?

Tags: gardening, permaculture

I am interested in permaculture, and have read some of the classic texts on the subject.  What are some good general ways to find other people in my local area who are doing the same to share ideas with and learn from?

Comment: Talk to people who seem to be doing anything related to sustainable living and sooner or later you will meet someone who shares your ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do a Google search for "Permaculture MYTOWN". Find anyone that is in to permaculture in your area. They will know other people.
2. Search for "cob", "humanure", "rocket stove" in your area. If you find a class on these topics, e.g. "Building a cob oven in your back yard", people at the class will help you get started.
3. Check/post in the [PERMIES.COM Regional](http://www.permies.com/forums/c/3/) section.
4. Visit your local farmers market, and find the farmer with the smallest operation - ask them!